# Files are empty after a git smudge

Tags: git, attributes

I have some issue while introducing git attributes in my project.

I'm trying to handle configuration files depending on the branch where we are. (develop if for dev environnement, valid for integration, etc ...).

After some researches I found the git attributes idea very useful and especially the filter attribute.

So now, I'm trying to code this. Actually i have some code that works well for me :

```
#!/bin/bash

############# Script parameters #############
while getopts "d" opt; do
 case $opt in
    d) source_conf="${branche}_dev_conf.txt" ; file_to_find="job_dev.properties" ;; 
 esac
done
########################################################

source_conf="${source_conf:-${branche}_conf.txt}"

file_to_find="${file_to_find:-job.properties}"

job_to_trt="$(find $PWD -type f -name $file_to_find)"
if [ ! -z "$job_to_trt" ] ; then 
    cp "$job_to_trt" "$backup_dir/$(basename $job_to_trt)"
    while read key value
    do
        echo -e "\t key=$key, value=$value" >> "$log_file"
        grep "$key=$value" "$backup_dir/$(basename $job_to_trt)" ; res="$?"
        if (( $res != 0 ))  ; then 
            sed -i "s|$key=.*|$key=$value|g" "$job_to_trt"
        fi 
    done < "$util_dir/conf/$source_conf"
fi

if [ "$(ls $branche_dir | wc -l)" -gt 10 ] ; then 
    for dir in $(ls -t $branche_dir | tail -n $(($(ls $branche_dir | wc -l) - 10)))
    do  
        rm -rf "$branche_dir/$dir"
    done 

fi
```

This script (depending on the 'd' parameter) is looking for job[_dev].properties in my git project and reset some variables in it if necessary.

This script is execute on clean and smudge operation.

But now is the problem, when someone else than me is trying to pull the project the both files job[_dev].properties are empty and i'm not understanding why ...

Am I missing something important ?

For information : 
Git version : 
    git version 1.7.1

.gitattributes :

```
job.properties filter=LHRJob
job_dev.properties filter=LHRJobDev
```

.gitconfig (global) :

```
[filter "LHRJob"]
  clean = /data/atl_sncftn/utils/util_git/util_lhr/cleanJob.sh
  smudge = /data/atl_sncftn/utils/util_git/util_lhr/cleanJob.sh
[filter "LHRJobDev"]
  clean = /data/atl_sncftn/utils/util_git/util_lhr/cleanJob.sh -d 
 smudge = /data/atl_sncftn/utils/util_git/util_lhr/cleanJob.sh -d
```

Comment: What is the content of your `.gitignore` file. Are the files committed and pushed with data inside ?

Comment: Your filter appears not to read from stdin, nor write to stdout. Since your Git is quite old (1.7.1) it does not support long-running filter processes, so reading stdin and writing stdout is *required* for each filter. A clean filter that reads nothing from stdin and writes nothing to stdout will cause the index version of the file to be empty; it is this empty file that will be committed.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer ... So i need to write something in the stdout ? If I write something like echo "foo", there will be foo in my files ?

May be it's a dummy question but i prefer to be sure ...

Comment: @torek I tried something from what you said yesterday. After the changes on my file made `cat $my_file >&1`. It solved my problem on commit, my files are no longer empty ... On commit ... 

But when someone is pulling the file from the repo the file becomes arrives empty ... I'm obviously missing something from what you explained but i don't know why ^^'

Comment: It might be worth using some of the lower level tools (e.g., `git cat-file`) to inspect what's in the repository. Note also that there's an inherent problem with clean and smudge filters: you *list* them (their names) in `.gitattributes` but you *define* them (the commands that go with those names) in `$HOME/.gitconfig` or `.git/config`. This tends to mean that at `git clone` time they may not be synchronized yet: the attribute says to run a smudge filter named X but there is no smudge filter named X defined.

Comment: Ok so i will try to figure it out ... 

I understand your point on synchronised time ... But for me, at the very best, if the filter is not declared in $HOME/.gitconfig the files should be touch, no ? 

Last question, do you think that an upgrade of git would solve this problem i.e do recent git versions allow to do what i want ?